# How to connect android to joomla database

Tags: php, android, joomla

I am a beginner to android . I want to connect my android application to joomla 1.5 database.
please help me....

Comment: I also did same to connect all smart phones to my joomla application

Answer (score 5):

Connecting to any specific technology database is not an option for Android application, You should expose webservice to fetch data from **any X technologies** database.

Answer (score 3):

You need to expose your datas from Joomla through a web service and consume it on your Android app.

This presentation could help you:
http://fr.slideshare.net/HermanPeeren/webservices-connecting-joomla-with-other-programs-4399412
And the doc of the Joomla API:
http://docs.joomla.org/API

Answer (score 3):

for interacting the android application to joomla database you have to use [web services](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service)

see the best [article](http://davidwalsh.name/web-service-php-mysql-xml-json) for web-service beginner.

Answer (score 0):

we did a more recent and stable RPC-JSON(Dojo & SMD compatible) adapter for Joomla and any other SQL & PHP based system . You simply pass queries and nested schemas which can have PHP functions in top. security is done by b&w listings.

its free, Dual(GPL&Custom)  and part of our mobile-app-ide : xapp-studio.com (download the Joomla plug).

the actual work is done by another project of us : xapp-php.com which turns out as universal PHP gateway.